# Are too Many native queries in Spring MVC with JPA project a normal deal?

Tags: spring-mvc

**Project Technology Stack**:I am working for a project which is using Spring MVC. We are using JPA for ORM.
The sql database is MySQL.

**Issue**: The Business logic has become a lot complex in the application. To fetch data from the application, code is using a lot of Native SQL queries with multiple JOINS.

This creates a lot of problem while creating Integration test cases. This happens due to the fact that when entity is persisted using JPA's entity Manager the entity is in First Level Cache. Now when the next fetch query(which is written in native SQL) tries to fetch the data, it cannot. This happens because native sql queries always goto the database whereas the 1st Level Cache synchronises with the database after the whole test case has executed.

I wanted to know if there is a workaround for this?

Comment: 'flush` before executing the query...

Comment: Or use non-native queries, and JPA should flush automatically for you.

Comment: @Deinum flush won't help. If I add flush I will have to do it before every native query. I have around 500-700 native queries currently in the project.